# List covers custom view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently having a issue with SwiftUI when I put "Grid" ([Github URL](https://github.com/SwiftUIExtensions/Grid)) in to a list, it gets covered by the next cell. But when I expand the "Text" the cell becomes larger.

```
List(0 ..< colorArray.count) { i in
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
    Text("a")
        .font(.body)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .lineLimit(nil)
    Grid {
        ForEach(self.colorArray[i], id: \.self) { color in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .foregroundColor(Color(color))
                .frame(width: 80.0, height:80.0)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color(UIColor.label),
                                lineWidth: 0.5)
            )
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
    .gridStyle(
        AutoColumnsGridStyle(minItemWidth: 80, itemHeight: 80, hSpacing: 8, vSpacing: 8)
    )
}
```

}

[image: Screenshot of my current result]
How can I make it that the "Grid" doesn't get covered up like in the picture below.
[image: This is the result I would like to get]

Comment: What happens if you add `.fixedSize()` to the grid? or `.frame(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to recreate this because your code is incomplete, but applying

```
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

either to `Grid` or the whole `VStack` should force the cell to have the right size.

Comment: This fixes the problem I had, but it creates a giant gap and each row from the List takes up half of the screen. Do you have any solutions for that?

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer - the code is incomlete. You would need to include code that I can copy and paste into Xcode - otherwise I don't know where the problems is coming from.